# firebase get child by month of birthday

Tags: javascript, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I'm looking to make query in firebase to get all child by month of birthday.
for e.g the month is april (04) so I want to get the user1,user2,user4 in my example
[image]

not sure if need to use in startAt query or what way to do it.

```
  let month = '04';
        firebase.ref('/UserTest').startAt(month).once('value',snapshot=>{
            snapshot.forEach((childSnapshot)=>{

            })
        })
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to store a field for month alone, then you can use `equal(month_here)` to be able to retrieve all users in month April:

```
  firebase.ref('/UserTest').orderByChild("month").equalTo(month).once('value',snapshot=>{
        snapshot.forEach((childSnapshot)=>{
        var users = childSnapshot.key;
        })
    })
```

This `var users = childSnapshot.key;` will retrieve the users

more info here:

https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/js/firebase.database.Query

Comment: I thought about this solution but I'm looking efficient way.

Comment: this is the best way in this case to retrieve all birthday in a specific month. Also if you want to use startAt(), you need to add first `orderByChild("birthday").startAt("04/19/1993')`

Comment: You can do orderByChild("birthday").startAt("04/19/1993').endAt("04/19/1994") but that will retrieve data depening on the day/month/date @AdirZoari

Answer (score 1):

The best (an easier) is to store an extra field in each user node with only the month and query on this field